# infinite loop due to buffer value -1?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, cin

I'm writing this program for class. It's supposed to take in a word 10 or less chars in size and change each char individually to uppercase using a `toupper()` call. The requirements of the assignment are to use `toupper()` on each individual char in an array that holds the word and the `'\n'`. Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char again = ' ';
    char word[11];

    for(int count=0; count<11; count++){
            word[count] = ' ';
    }

    while(true){

        for(int clear=0; clear < 11; clear++){
            word[clear] = ' ';
        }

        system("CLS");
        cout << "Please provide a lowercase word!" << endl;
        cin.getline(word, 11);

        for(int letter = 0; letter < 11; letter++){
            system("CLS");
            if(letter < 10){
                word[letter] = toupper(word[letter]);
            }
            for(int printw = 0; printw < 11; printw++){
                cout << word[printw];
            }
            Sleep(200);
        }

        cout << endl;

        while(true){
            cout << "Would you like to Repeat or Quit? (R/Q)" << endl;
            cin.get(again);
            cin.get();

            tolower(again);

            if(again == 'r' || again == 'q'){
                break;
            }
            else{
                cout << "That was an invalide input!" << endl;
            }
        }

        if(again == 'q'){
            break;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The program works just fine for 1 - 10 char words, but if the user decides to enter a string larger than 10 chars, the program will uppercase the first 10 and then hit an infinite loop when it asks if the user would like to try again. When that happens it will continue to return *"That was an invalid output!"* and the next prompt to repeat or quit on the next line. It will not wait for input, and I've tried clearing the buffer with `cin.ignore()`.

I tried checking the values in the buffer with several `cout << cin.get() << endl;` line and they all come back with the ascii value of -1. I assume this means it is throwing a failbit exception, but I'm not actually sure.

Comment: You've got way too many loops in this program. You don't need the nested while(true) loop. You don't need the printw loop, just cout << word; And you don't even need your clear loops: if you want to clear a C-style string, just do word[0]='\0' instead of a for-loop.

Comment: The nested while loop is there to prevent the user from inputting something other than r or q and give them a chance at deciding what they want to do if they do input something else instead of assuming one thing or the other. Is there a better or more preferred way of accomplishing that?

Thank you for the rest though, I didn't know cout << word; worked and I wasn't aware of how to clear a c-style string!

Comment: Yes, you're probably stuck with the inner while. Glad the other points were useful)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a character array of fixed size, you should use a `string` to store your input. You can use `getline` to read a line from `cin` like this:

```
string input;
...
getline(cin, input);
```

This will read the entire line, regardless of how long it is or how many characters you actually process.

Comment: Normally I would do that, but the class assignment requires me to use a char array. Unless you are suggesting I read it into a string and then create a char array to equate to the first 10 chars of the string?

Comment: Important to tell the OP that this will grow with the input, whereas his fixed size array of 11 characters obviously won't and writes beyond its size will result in undefined behaviour, including trashing his loop variable.

Comment: @JosiahSaly does the assignment specify whether input may be more than 10 characters on a line? If not, then you probably don't need to worry about it.

Comment: The assignment doesn't specify the size of input, just the size of the array and I don't want to assume the input will match because I feel like that would be bad practice and I wouldn't want her to test an 11 or greater string and that count against me.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing here is the expected behaviour of `cin.getline(char* s, streamsize n)` 
From C++ ref for `istream::getline`:

> **The failbit flag is set** if the function extracts no characters, or **if
>   the delimiting character is not found once (n-1) characters have
>   already been written to s**.

If a user types a word longer than 10 chars, then cin writes the first 10 chars to `word` and sets its internal flag to fail as no delimiter `\n` (newline) has been seen.

If you want to stick to your current solution, you could overcome this with:

```
const int SIZE = 11;
```

...

```
cin.getline(word, SIZE);
if (cin.fail() && cin.gcount() == SIZE-1) { // failed because user entered a word longer than 10 chars
    word[SIZE-1] = '\0';    // make sure to null terminate
    cin.clear();            // clear the failure from cin
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');  // ignore the leftover input from cin until next newline
}
```

You need to both clear the failbit and ignore the leftover input. 256 is simply a number large enough, to be super safe you can use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` (don't forget to `#include <limits>`)

PS You might be better off reading a char at a time with cin.get(char& c) though.